# res.send Not sending any data - Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am working on this calculator app using Express.js and when I use the res.send Method I am not receiving any kind of response now.
I expect my webpage to send me the sum as in the calculator.js file.
I am using nodemon as well.
This is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <form method="POST">
    <input name='num1' placeholder='num1' type='text'>
    <input name='num2' placeholder='num2' type='text'>
  <button
    type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button></form>
  
  <h1 class='answer'></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

This is calculator.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const {
  json,
  urlencoded
} = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
});;

app.post("/", function (req, res) {

  console.log(req.body);
  var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  var sum = num1 + num2;
  res.send(sum);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port port!`))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `res.send()` to send `number`, it will be sent as a [http status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). You can simply convert calculated `sum` to string and then send it:

```
res.send(sum.toString())
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. That's why my code was not working and I was getting that HTTP status code.

Answer (score -1):

`res.send` has been deprecated in the latest version of Express (4.17.1).
Using `res.sendStatus` instead solved my problem.

Comment: This means you're sending the result of the addition as the HTTP statuscode. Is this really what you want?

Comment: ``res.send`` is **not** deprecated. https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send

Comment: @eol No, that wasn't what I intended. The other answer tells me where I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes I saw in the terminal that it is deprecated. Not sure of this conflict then.

Comment: It is deprecated if you send a number otherwise it is not...